# Fetch video files from drupal using graphQL queries

Tags: drupal, graphql, apollo

I am beginner in GraphQL and Drupal.
I created an article with composable example schema in drupal and added video and image fields and added video and image contents to it. I want to access the image and video from my react app using apollo-graphql. Or it would be enough if I know how to query it using graphiQL. I can query other String fields, there is no problem in that. But I am clueless how to query video/images.
Can anybody give an advice?